# Partitioning customer id on timestamp based on date differences

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I want to get a rank/row_number for each customer but keep the rank the same if subsequent transactions are made within 24 hours.

This is what I've tried to do:

```sql
with x as (
    select 214142446 as unique_customer_id, 19331177 as transaction_id, to_timestamp('26/04/2017 11:28:01', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as log_date union all
    select 214142446, 1193324450, to_timestamp('26/04/2017  12:29:50', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') union all
    select 214142446, 1193327391, to_timestamp('26/04/2017  12:42:17', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') union all
    select 214142446, 1194753492, to_timestamp('03/05/2017  14:56:33', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') union all
    select 214142446, 1198679862, to_timestamp('23/05/2017  11:11:46', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') union all
    select 214142446, 1198893043, to_timestamp('24/05/2017  11:23:33', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') union all
    select 214142446, 1198948574, to_timestamp('24/05/2017  16:12:35', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') union all
    select 214142446, 1198952915, to_timestamp('24/05/2017  17:04:10', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') union all
    select 214142446, 1200182526, to_timestamp('30/05/2017  14:23:43', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') union all
    select 214142446, 1202206887, to_timestamp('07/06/2017  14:19:33', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') union all
    select 214142446, 1202163318, to_timestamp('08/06/2017  13:04:01', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') union all
    select 214142446, 1203934169, to_timestamp('14/06/2017  17:08:58', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') union all
    select 214142446, 1205508321, to_timestamp('20/06/2017  13:05:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') union all
    select 214142446, 1205541102, to_timestamp('20/06/2017  14:35:41', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') union all
    select 214142446, 1205562693, to_timestamp('20/06/2017  15:58:01', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') union all
    select 214142446, 1206273894, to_timestamp('23/06/2017  10:18:45', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') union all
    select 2115686902, 1231603750, to_timestamp('06/10/2017  13:47:20', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') union all
    select 2115686902, 1231697368, to_timestamp('07/10/2017  12:34:08', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') union all
    select 2115686902, 1231699273, to_timestamp('07/10/2017  12:46:01', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') union all
    select 2115686902, 1231699882, to_timestamp('07/10/2017  12:52:28', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') union all
    select 2115686902, 1231975996, to_timestamp('09/10/2017  20:06:47', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') union all
    select 2115686902, 1232073502, to_timestamp('10/10/2017  17:05:06', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') union all
    select 2115686902, 1232074795, to_timestamp('10/10/2017  17:15:16', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') union all
    select 2115686902, 1232250513, to_timestamp('12/10/2017  09:15:41', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') union all
    select 2115686902, 1232251114, to_timestamp('12/10/2017  09:21:43', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') union all
    select 2115686902, 1232371321, to_timestamp('13/10/2017  11:50:36', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') union all
    select 2115686902, 1232391230, to_timestamp('13/10/2017  15:07:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') union all
    select 2115686902, 1232392844, to_timestamp('13/10/2017  15:23:44', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') union all
    select 2115686902, 1232450858, to_timestamp('14/10/2017  08:43:02', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') union all
    select 2115686902, 1232451164, to_timestamp('14/10/2017  08:51:17', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') union all
    select 2115686902, 1232755473, to_timestamp('17/10/2017  09:11:38', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') union all
    select 2115686902, 1232766588, to_timestamp('17/10/2017  11:15:38', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') union all
    select 2115686902, 232989319, to_timestamp('19/10/2017  13:42:25', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
)
select *
    , sum (case when hour_diff > 24 then 1 else 0 end)
     over (partition by unique_customer_id order by log_date rows unbounded preceding) + 1 as customer_trxn_cnt
from (
    select *
    , datediff(hour, lag(log_date, 1) over (partition by unique_customer_id order by log_date)::timestamp, log_date::timestamp) as hour_diff
    from x
    )
order by unique_customer_id, log_date
;
```

The problem with this is that it only considers the previous transaction log_date when determining whether or not to keep the rank the same. I'm looking for the output to group transactions made within 24 hours of each other and assign the same rank to them:

```
unique_customer_id|booking_id|to_timestamp       |customer_trxn_cnt|
------------------|----------|-------------------|-----------------|
           4142446|  19331177|2017-04-26 12:28:01|                1|
           4142446|  19332445|2017-04-26 13:29:50|                1|
           4142446|  19332739|2017-04-26 13:42:17|                1|
           4142446|  19475349|2017-05-03 15:56:33|                2|
           4142446|  19867986|2017-05-23 12:11:46|                3|
           4142446|  19889304|2017-05-24 12:23:33|                4|
           4142446|  19894857|2017-05-24 17:12:35|                4|
           4142446|  19895291|2017-05-24 18:04:10|                4|
           4142446|  20018252|2017-05-30 15:23:43|                5|
           4142446|  20220688|2017-06-07 15:19:33|                6|
           4142446|  20216331|2017-06-08 14:04:01|                6|
           4142446|  20393416|2017-06-14 18:08:58|                7|
           4142446|  20550832|2017-06-20 14:05:00|                8|
           4142446|  20554110|2017-06-20 15:35:41|                8|
           4142446|  20556269|2017-06-20 16:58:01|                8|
           4142446|  20627389|2017-06-23 11:18:45|                9|
          15686902|  23160370|2017-10-06 14:47:20|                1|
          15686902|  23169738|2017-10-07 13:34:08|                1|
          15686902|  23169923|2017-10-07 13:46:01|                1|
          15686902|  23169982|2017-10-07 13:52:28|                1|
          15686902|  23197596|2017-10-09 21:06:47|                2|
          15686902|  23207352|2017-10-10 18:05:06|                2|
          15686902|  23207475|2017-10-10 18:15:16|                3|
          15686902|  23225053|2017-10-12 10:15:41|                4|
          15686902|  23225114|2017-10-12 10:21:43|                4|
          15686902|  23237131|2017-10-13 12:50:36|                5|
          15686902|  23239120|2017-10-13 16:07:00|                5|
          15686902|  23239284|2017-10-13 16:23:44|                5|
          15686902|  23245088|2017-10-14 09:43:02|                6|
          15686902|  23245114|2017-10-14 09:51:17|                6|
          15686902|  23275543|2017-10-17 10:11:38|                7|
          15686902|  23276658|2017-10-17 12:15:38|                7|
          15686902|  23298931|2017-10-19 14:42:25|                8|
```

Was thinking a cumulative sum of hour_diff resetting when it reaches over 24 and then doing a `row_number()` against that?
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
select x.*,
       sum (case when prev_ld > log_date - interval '24 hour'
                 then 0 else 1
            end) over (partition by unique_customer_id
                       order by log_date
                       rows unbounded preceding
                      )  as customer_trxn_cnt
from (select x.*,
             lag(log_date, 1) over (partition by unique_customer_id order by log_date) as prev_ld
      from x
     ) x
order by unique_customer_id, log_date;
```

Comment: I think that's similar to what I done already. The problem is that query only compares the previous date whereas there are situations where say, 3 transactions are made 16 apart from each other, the first two transactions will be ranked 1 whereas the last one should be ranked 2 (and not 1 across all 3 transactions)

Comment: @AK91 . . . This "breaks" the sequence when there is a gap of 1 day or more.  The sequence can be arbitrarily long, as long as the adjacent values are close enough.